# Passing commands to shellinabox from java program

Tags: java, linux

I have a Web page integrated with the **shellinabox** tool. where user can come in execute the UNIX commands from the browser.

I have some saved scripts which user can select and run. Is there any possibility to send UNIX commands to the **shellinabox** instance from JAVA program implicitly so that user can see the same in the VT emulator running in the browser.

for Eg: `shellinabox --exec` something like this

Its really a new area for me.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make a running C program available on the web browser. This worked for me :

```
    shellinaboxd --service='/shell':'harshit':'harshit':'/home/harshit':'./a.out'
```

This made my program's executable a.out running and I could interact with it on the browser.
The url was :

```
    localhost:4200/shell
```

Actually the syntax is :

```
    shellinaboxd --service=<service-url>:<username>:<group>:<home-directory>:<command>
```